# Should the [via] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I browsed over the list of questions under [via](/questions/tagged/via) tags, most of them means only the English word **via**.

Some of them refers to the **via** link on a website or an app. This part I'm not so sure, I do feel it's not helpful.

Several questions tagged with [via](/questions/tagged/via) refers to the HTTP Via header, thus more appropriately using the more precise [http-via-header](/questions/tagged/http-via-header) (which I just created).

Should the tag [via](/questions/tagged/via) be burninated?

Comment: Burninate with *righteous* fire!  There are only a handful of questions.  When editing tags, be sure to improve other areas of the question as well!  The tagging is awful on most of these...

Comment: Burn via hellfire! *(Ok, I know that wasn't sound so right...)*

Comment: +1 Crikey, I just voted for outright burnination without arguing about it first. That doesn't happen often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[All gone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/via)

[image: Killed!]